# linker error when 'archive' a sample swift project with ooVoo framework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, oovoo

I have a sample swift video chat app that I build with the help from `ooVoo framework`. The app builds and runs as expected when I simply run it from `Xcode` on my `iPhone 5s` phone. When I switch the device to '`Generic iOS Device`' and run '`Product'->'Archive`' to get the app ready for test, flight I get a linker error.

> `ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because`
>   '*/Users/Shared/ooVooSDK/lib/ooVooSDK.framework/ooVooSDK(SdkResult.o)*'
>   was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for
>   bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for
>   architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

What am I missing? We have the `ooVoo framework` version `2.2.0.72`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable bitcode for your app if all the frameworks aren't built with bitcode support.

[image]